# live log of php engine

Tags: php, centos7

Is there any way to watch php activities online? I am looking for something like apache logs that I can I run `tail -f /var/log/httpd/access.log` in the terminal and then open the URL in a browser and see what apache prints.

So, I am seeking for similar thing for php web pages. The php is 7.2

UPDATE1:

Trying to watch system log with `tail -f /var/log/messages`, I get many messages similar to this in the terminal when the page is reloaded from browser.

```
python: SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on the directory /var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin.#012#012*****  Plugin httpd_write_content (92.2 confidence) suggests   ***************#012#012If you want to allow httpd to have write access on the admin directory#012Then you need to change the label on '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'#012Do#012# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'#012# restorecon -v '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'#012#012*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.83 confidence) suggests   ******************#012#012If you want to allow httpd to unified#012Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_unified' boolean.#012#012Do#012setsebool -P httpd_unified 1#012#012*****  Plugin catchall (1.41 confidence) suggests   **************************#012#012If you believe that httpd should be allowed write access on the admin directory by default.#012Then you should report this as a bug.#012You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.#012Do#012allow this access for now by executing:#012# ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd#012# semodule -i my-httpd.pp#012
```

It is an ugly message! I think I have to run `semanage fcontext -a -t` with some paths. Not sure which paths exactly!

UPDATE2:

A more clear log is available with the following command

```
[root@localhost html]# sealert -l e254cabb-7005-4a3c-8f91-8620c924c5e0
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on the file /var/www/html/ow_includes/config.php.

*****  Plugin httpd_write_content (92.2 confidence) suggests   ***************

If you want to allow httpd to have write access on the config.php file
Then you need to change the label on '/var/www/html/ow_includes/config.php'
Do
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/ow_includes/config.php'
# restorecon -v '/var/www/html/ow_includes/config.php'

*****  Plugin catchall_boolean (7.83 confidence) suggests   ******************

If you want to allow httpd to unified
Then you must tell SELinux about this by enabling the 'httpd_unified' boolean.

Do
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1

*****  Plugin catchall (1.41 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that httpd should be allowed write access on the config.php file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'httpd' --raw | audit2allow -M my-httpd
# semodule -i my-httpd.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Target Objects                /var/www/html/ow_includes/config.php [ file ]
Source                        httpd
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/httpd
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          localhost.localdomain
Source RPM Packages
Target RPM Packages
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.13.1-192.el7_5.6.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     localhost.localdomain
Platform                      Linux localhost.localdomain
                              3.10.0-862.11.6.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Aug 14
                              21:49:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   108
First Seen                    2018-09-02 16:51:25 +0430
Last Seen                     2018-09-02 23:00:19 +0430
Local ID                      e254cabb-7005-4a3c-8f91-8620c924c5e0

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(1535913019.143:9913): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=5121 comm="httpd" name="config.php" dev="dm-0" ino=18219610 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0 tclass=file


Hash: httpd,httpd_t,httpd_sys_content_t,file,write
```

Comment: What do you expect to see in these php logs?  If apache is the web server, why wouldn't you use apache's logs?

Comment: I am getting some error about recursive write permissions. Although I did `chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html`, I don't know which file or folder it is actually accessing. I haven't written the code. It is part of the installation of a website.

Comment: You lost me now, not sure how watching access logs relates to your last comment.

Comment: I have read that php can be run with a built-in server `-S`. When I run `php72 -S http://w.x.y.z`, I get `Invalid address` error.

Comment: It seems that by running with `-S`, I can watch live logs of what php is doing. Not sure though...

Comment: You could run strace on the php process.  That's much different than an apache access log though.

Comment: `ps aux | grep php*` says there is no process.

Comment: is php running under mod_php? btw, php -S takes an address, not a protocol.  Specify ip:port, not http://..

Comment: There is `/etc/httpd/conf.d/php72-php.conf:<IfModule  mod_php7.c>` and conf.d is included in httpd conf `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`. I also see `php7_module (shared)` in the output of `httpd -M`.

Comment: Trying `php72 -S w.x.y.z:80` says `reason: Cannot assign requested address`. I think that means httpd is using 80.

Comment: yes, apache would already be listening on 80.  This may be useful, https://hackernoon.com/debugging-a-php-application-with-strace-4d0ae59f880b, but probably overkill for debugging an error

Comment: Please see  UPDATE1

Comment: yeah, you can allow that access with audit2allow but this really is more of a sysadmin issue than a programming issue.

Comment: Well, I haven't seen that problem with Ubuntu. This is Centos. I also think that is a admin problem. I wonder which commands should I run?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [`SELinux`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) issue, as is apparent by the logs messages...

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/httpd from write access on the directory /var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin.#012#012*****  
...
If you want to allow httpd to have write access on the admin directory
Then you need to change the label on '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'

 semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'
 restorecon -v '/var/www/html/ow_userfiles/plugins/admin'
```

Start with the first error, do exactly as it states.. and see if that resolves e others.

If other errors still exist after running these commands, follow the res of the instructions in the very clear error message you were presented.

Comment: Well `setsebool -P httpd_unified 1` which is the third command did the job.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php « tail » from my notes to play around.

It is similar to **tail -n 5 access.log**

This will answer the last 5 lines of *access.log*.

To make it acting like *tail -f*, just use a loop.

```
$check = "access.log";
$end = "5";

$fp= fopen($check, "r");
$count=0;
while($line = fgetss($fp))
$count++;
// echo "Total lines ".$count.PHP_EOL;
fclose($fp);

$start = $count - $end;

$file = new SplFileObject($check);
$file->seek($start);
for($i = 0; !$file->eof() && $i < $end; $i++) {
  echo $file->current(); 
  $file->next();
}
```

It is also very fast, the whole file isn't taken in memory, just like tail.

[SplFileObject](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.splfileobject.php)